# Is there a way to reduce high-dimensional feature space to an array of 2d tSNEs ordered along a chosen dimension?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, tsne

Let's say we have 4096-d vectors (via a CNN fully-connected layer) and often we use tSNE to visualize the space, sometimes [in combo with Jonker-Volgenant](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/lapjv/) to assign it to a grid. When applied to image datasets such as museum collections we can get "views" [like this](https://experiments.withgoogle.com/curator-table): [image: screenshot from Google Arts & Culture Experiment "Curator Table"]

My question is whether there's a way to control for a 3rd dimension when reducing the feature space? To take the museum example, instead of reducing to a single grid, could I reduce it to a stack of tSNE grids, binned/controlled by e.g. year of artwork creation as the z-dimension while maintaining consistent x- and y-axes, such that in the result "view", one could "travel" through time and get a sense of how (for example) development of paint colors influenced the history of iconography?

(I'm coming at this from a designer perspective, apologies in advance for ignorance of math. )

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially modify the tSNE algorithm to add a third (fixed) dimension, and have it only optimize the x and y as before.
But the results will likely be less consistent across time, and choosing the right scaling of that axis may need some experimentation.